# Introduction to Azure Create a virtual machine / Azure Cloud Shell - How should I type admin password?

Tags: azure

I am currently having "Welcome to Azure" course on M"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/welcome-to-azure".

In the section of "Introduction to Azure  Create a virtual machine " I need to type admin password but I cannot type or enter any character into the command line when it is asked to enter a password.

Anyone had this issue before ???
And how could you type your admin password ???

[image]

Comment: Maybe when type their are not visible in shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment the password is not visible in the shell. You can actually type the password and once after that, it will be prompted to `confirm it again`

So no need to worry, Just type your password and move forward.

[image]

*Happy Learning !*

Comment: @CandaşSaldıroğlu happy to help. Please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it can help other community members